# "Void methods cannot return a value" for 'valid'(?) lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda

I'm currently try to improve my Java 8 skills. But now I am facing the following problem which I do not understand.

Let's assume the following peace of code:

```
List<String> words = generateNewList();
words.stream().filter(w -> w.length() < 4).forEach(print());
```

Now I want to create a lambda as a method reference which can be used in the `filter` method instead of actually write the lambda expression in the method call. My approach was:

```
Consumer<String> shortFilter = w -> w.length() < 4;
words.stream().filter(shortFilter).forEach(print());
```

The problem is, Eclipse shows me an error for `w -> w.length() < 4` which says: "Void methods cannot return a value"

It just getting more confusing for me, cause the following changing removes the error:

```
   Consumer<String> shortFilter = w -> shorterThen4(w);
   ...
}

public boolean shorterThen4(String w) {
    return w.length() < 4;
}
```

Thank you for any idea, hint or remark.

Comment: *"Let's assume the following peace of code"* My Java lambda syntax-fu is weak, but surely `.forEach(print());` is *calling* `print()` and passing its return value into `forEach`?

Comment: The filter() method expects a Predicate, not a Consumer. A Predicate returns a boolean. A Consumer returns void.

Comment: From [the JavaDoc of `Consumer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html): *"Represents an operation that accepts a single input argument **and returns no result.**"* (my emphasis).

Comment: (Side note: The phrase is "shorter than," not "shorter then." So `shorterThan4` rather than `shorterThen4`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to assign you lambda expression to a Predicate and not a Consumer because as JB Nizet commented - a Predicate returns a boolean and a Consumer returns void.

```
Predicate<String> isLessThan4 = w -> w.length() < 4;
List<String> words = generateNewList();
words.stream().filter(isLessThan4).forEach(print());
```

You might want to look at the Java Documentation for [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) and [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) to understand a bit more how to use both Functional Interfaces.

I hope this helps!